# On Cupcake Wars, how do they get the winning cupcakes to the event?

Tags: production, ending, reality-tv, cupcake-wars

At the end of each episode of *Cupcake Wars*, two teams have created elaborate decorative stands that support 1000 cupcakes each. The winning team has their decorative stand(s) and cupcakes brought to an event.

[image]

My question is, how do they transport the stands and the cupcakes? If they have to drive several miles, wouldn't many of the cupcakes be marred or damaged while being transported? Are the stands transported with all the cupcakes in place (which seems unlikely), and if not, who removes all the cupcakes, packs them for transit, and then places all 1000 cupcakes again at the venue?

Comment: I'm gonna be honest... I'm not even actually sure that the cakes made when filming the show are the ones actually taken to the party... It could be weeks later for all we know.

Comment: @Catija Wow, great point!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cupcakes are a lie... essentially.

The "event" is not that night.

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/33vst1/ama_request_anyone_who_has_been_on_cupcake_wars/cqp0d6x/):

> 2) The in-kitchen filming did take place in one day, but not necessarily the staged drama. The final challenge that I mentioned before, where they had to make 1000 cupcakes, was for a Hollywood event that was supposedly that night. It was actually weeks later.

All of the cupcakes actually made that day are [apparently given to charity](http://www.mediamikes.com/2012/09/florian-bellanger-talks-about-judging-on-the-food-network-series-cupcake-wars/):

> **MG:** After each show, the winners always get to go to these parties; why aren’t the judges invited?
>   **FB:** Of course since it is TV, they make you think the party is that night. It would be impossible to have the show shoot the same days as the events. On TV, we make it look like they go straight to the parties. They show up at a later date and it makes it more difficult. The winning display is saved but they have to re-bake all of the thousand cupcakes. The day of shooting those cupcakes go to charity. Sometimes the contestants are coming from the East Coast and the party is in Los Angeles. So it is a big of trip sometimes for these contestants.